# "seek" without preposition sounds weird

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, writing-advice

I am writing the following sentence (I made it shorter for this question):

> To achieve a better bound, we seek graphs with the following property.

I read that using the phrase "seek for" is not recommended or even incorrect. Is my sentence OK?

Thank you

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your use of "seek", but proofreading questions are considered off topic here, so I have to vote to close.

Comment: Additionally, I’d replace "the following property" with the actual property itself, or use a colon to separate "the following property" from the actual property. But that is totally opinion!

Comment: @Pam Where can I ask questions like this? I could not find a StackExchange that fits better than this one. As for your second comment, I agree, I just posted the sentence like this to make it shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is OK.

*Seek* takes a direct object.

*Seek for* is understandable, but I don't think a native speaker would ever say it.

Comment: The phrasal verb "seek out" is another possibility.

Comment: Also in the past tense something is 'much sought after'.

Comment: _Look for_ is probly used orders of magnitude more often than _seek_ in English conversation. It's not surprising _seek_ sounds strange as a transitive verb; we're not used to it any more.